# MVC page content displays twice in same browser window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

MVC3 Web site displays (razor ) views normally in most cases but when browsing to some views the complete web page ( header to footer ) is displayed twice in the same browser window one page on top of the other. And then nothing on either page works correctly.

Has anyone seen this strange behavior in MVC3 razor before? What could cause this behavior?

Orgbrat

Comment: is it predictable enough that you can debug when it happens?

Comment: Are you using @Html.Partial or @ Html.RenderPartial anywhere?

Comment: Zach, Yes it always does this when browsing to paticular views now. I thought somehow it might be calling the controller's function for that view twice but it only hits the function once in debug.

Comment: Splash-X, Yes I am using @Html.Partial in the _Layout page for Logon, Search and Footer code blocks

Comment: Splash-X, But those code sections have been working correctly for weeks. Although I could have changed something else that could have had some strange effect.

Comment: try throwing up some code. the view that is problematic and the controller action for that view. maybe something will jump out us.

Comment: Update -- OK this strange behavior is only happening when using Internet Explorer ( IE9 in this case ). I ran the web site in both Google and Mozilla browsers and the web site works completely as expected. So why is IE9 acting so strangely?

Comment: @Orgbrat, you should update your question with that information and include some source.

Answer (score 0):

Use F12 developer tools to debug this. Compare IE/FF/Chrome. I've found some anomalies in IE9/CSS - mostly missing elements or a few elements duplicated. I have never heard of entire pages being duplicated. FF/Chrome didn't show the missing/duplicate element behavior. If you can come up with a small repro in IE9 (that renders correctly in FF/Chrome), send it to me and I'll forward it to the IE team.